# Vector Calculus - In a Pac-Man enclosed circle, why is one of these solved integrals negative?

Tags: calculus, integration, circles

I have a question that I need someone to clarify for me. It's from this problem.

"Observer the following Pac-Man enclosed by the circle x^2+y^2=1 and the equation y=|x| as pictured below. Evaluate the following integrals"
(picture below)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsuav.jpg)

My two integral answers are correct: the first one being zero, and the second one being -sqrt(2)/3.

But now it's asking "why one of these integral answers is negative. I said that the area right below the x-axis had more area than the one above, and it's evident in the picture. But that isn't correct. What is the best way to answer that question.

EDIT: I've updated the picture for better quality.

Comment: It's difficult to read the image.

Comment: ok just saying, if it was a real Pac-Man, it would be x = |y|

Comment: ok, but it's asking why is it negative though. Written explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first integral is zero, because the Pacman is symmetric about $x=0$.  For every positive value of $x$ there is a corresponding negative value.  But for the second integral, there is more negative $y$ region than positive $y$ region.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.